# What is the best audio file format to stream on both iPhone and Android

Tags: android, ios

My client do have 10000+ audio songs on a server, he does want to develop an iPhone and Android app to play those songs. He is willing to convert the audio files for any given format.

So what is the best format store those files on the server to consume in iOS and Android ?

Comment: ios audio file stream supports these audio types
AIFF/AIFC/WAVE/CAF/NeXT/ADTS/MPEG Audio Layer 3/AAC

Comment: .WAV is best audio format for streaming that works well on Android and iOS without any problem

Comment: Since wav is huge, consider bundling whatever decoder you need with your app, that way you can pick the audio format best suited for both size and sound quality. For example ogg seems to have a bunch of libraries for both iOS and android.

Answer (score 1):

OGG is the best I've used so far on both [Android](http://radzio.github.io/AndroidOggStreamPlayer/) and [iOS](http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2012/08/07/precompiled-ogg-vorbis-libraries-for-ios/).

Here's [the list](https://wiki.xiph.org/Vorbis_Software_Players) of libraries for this for other platforms as well.

Answer (score 0):

The best format used by many well known streaming sites like SoundCloud is:
-> 128kbps transcoded mp3

Everything you need to stream is preferred to be in 128kbps transcoded mp3.
Hope that help somebody.